# I want to create a responsive star rating in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, mouseevent

This is my HTML

```
       <div id="starRatings">
         <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
         <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
         <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
         <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
         <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
```

This is my Javascript

```
const starRating = $("#starRatings").children();
    for (let i = 0; i < starRating.length; i++) {
        starRating[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
           
            for (let j = 1; j <= starRating.length; j++) {
                              
                $(starRating[j]).removeClass("checked");
                
            }
            for (let j = 1; j> i; j--) {
               
                $(starRating[j]).addClass("checked");
                console.log(starRating[j])  
            }
        });
        
        starRating[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
            for (let j = 1; j <= starRating.length; j++) {
                $(starRating[j]).addClass("checked");
                console.log(j)  
            }
            for (let j = 1; j> i; j--) {
                $(starRating[j]).removeClass("checked");
                console.log(j)  
            }

             });

           
            starRating[i].addEventListener("click", function() {    
                for (let j = 1; j <= starRating.length; j++) {
                $(starRating[j]).addClass("checked");
                
            }
            for (let j = 1; j> i; j--)  {
                $(starRating[j]).removeClass("checked");
                
            }

             });       
        }
```

The class checked simply gives the stars an orange colour and I want one to be orange at all times. I want the others to turn orange on mouse enter and back to grey on mouse leave AND when the user actually wants to click on a number of stars, they remain orange, even after mouse leave, for this im guessing I need an if statement somewhere.

I realise it should be simple and I've got wayyy too many for loops, but im losing my mind!
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you an example with jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/mp4oze3f/

CSS

```
 .et-app-sr {
  border: 0;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    word-wrap: normal !important
}
.et-app-rating-stars {
    height: 4em;
    display: flex
}

.et-app-rating-star {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.et-app-rating-star .selected {
    display: none;
    color: #edff71
}

.et-app-rating-star.select i, .et-app-rating-star.highlight i {
    display: none
}

.et-app-rating-star.select .selected, .et-app-rating-star.highlight .selected {
    display: block
}

.et-app-rating-star:focus {
    outline: 1px solid #000
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$('[data-star]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('select');
  $(this).prevAll('[data-star]').addClass('select');
  $(this).nextAll('[data-star]').removeClass('select');
  $(this).parent().find('input').val($(this).data('star'));
});
$('[data-star]').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('highlight');
  $(this).prevAll('[data-star]').addClass('highlight');
  $(this).nextAll('[data-star]').removeClass('highlight');
});
$('[data-star]').on('mouseout', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  $(this).prevAll('[data-star]').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="et-app-rating-stars">
  <input type="hidden">
  <button class="et-app-rating-star" data-star="1">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="et-app-sr">Rating: 1 star</span>
  </button>
  <button class="et-app-rating-star" data-star="2">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="et-app-sr">Rating: 2 star</span>
  </button>
  <button class="et-app-rating-star" data-star="3">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="et-app-sr">Rating: 3 star</span>
  </button>
  <button class="et-app-rating-star" data-star="4">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="et-app-sr">Rating: 4 star</span>
  </button>
  <button class="et-app-rating-star" data-star="5">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star selected" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="et-app-sr">Rating: 5 star</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I used more than you need, I change icons, you can look at the logic and do something like this